# How to avoid ltablex from splitting a table?

Tags: tables, longtable, tabu, ltablex

I'm using the `ltablex` package because I have some large tables which have to splitted on multiple pages. But I have much more small tables (with `tabularx`), which don't need to be splitted. But they where splitted :/

How can I avoid that for explicit tables?

I inserted these tables with:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lcX}
```

So I added no floating position tag, like `!h` or `t` or something else. I tried it with these, but no change. Only with the float-package and the option `H` they where not splitted, but then they are on the explicit position in text, what I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that `ltablex` affects all `tabularx` is not the best feature of the package, you could instead use `ltxtable` package but anyway with `ltablex` as with normal `tabularx` if you want the tabke to float it must be inside a `table` environment, and once inside such an environment it will not split as `table` makes a box. You can not add float options such as `[h]` to `tabular` or `tabularx`.

Comment: thanks for the hint. Inside the `table`environment it works now :)